# What header do I need to use the javascript key

Tags: parse-platform

What header do I need to use the javascript key

I've been using

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('X-Parse-Application-Id', 'j4CT1qeW9wI1AvNcu7HGhwm08vQTFGnf3scYgSI3');
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('X-Parse-REST-API-Key', 'E9DMy4x4LAqdIinhNDPIXQn90naWL80jc4rTsk0t');
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to set the application id and javascript key for general parse js. Those keys are set like this, however:
https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/web/existing

If you are doing a REST API request as you are showing, then you use the keys you showed. You can find the values if you go to the parse web interface, go to your app, go to settings, then on the left click "Keys".

Assuming you are using the correct key values, you are setting the header for that request correctly. What is going wrong with your request?

**Edit:**

If you want to make a REST API call without exposing your REST key, write a cloud code function that makes the REST call for them. That way they call the cloud function using the javascript key, and the cloud function calls REST with the REST API key (but the user won't see it). Then the REST call returns data to the cloud function, and the cloud function returns the data to the client through the response.

Comment: Thanks but The docs also say do not use the rest key on the client side code.

Comment: @SuperUberDuper You only asked what header you need to use. If you meant something more like "what should I use instead", then one possibility is to write cloud code functions that call the rest api. Your client code would only call these cloud functions, which could then return the same result as your previous rest api code. This way the rest api key is not exposed but you have the same functionality.

Comment: The java script key is designed to be used client as it adheres to clp

Comment: @SuperUberDuper I understand that the javascript key is supposed to be client side. Can you please make it more clear what you are trying to do? I showed how to use the javascript key and I outlined how you can do a REST request without exposing the REST key. Are neither of these a solution to your problem? As you can see here, the REST API key is the one you must use for the request you're doing:
http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/javascript-and-user-authentication-for-the-rest-api/